# Tried pushing two build none of it showing in either in testflight or activity tab

Tags: ios, apple-store, apns, testflight

Is there any policy change by Apple Connect while pushing to testflight. I tried pushing two build none of it showing in either in testflight or activity tab. Any help here ?

I normally build app with distribution certificate and upload it to App Store. Problem is, that it won’t appear in testflight tab. I can see that build in Activity tab and App Store tab, but not in testflight. Any one faced this recently ?

Screenshot show what am getting while uploading same build number means build is uploaded but not showing.

[image]
I didn't get any mail from apple about error.
[image]

Comment: How does your screenshot relate to the question you are asking? The screenshot indicates a specific issue, did you resolve this already?

Comment: screenshot is whenever i uploaded same build its give error means build is uploaded but not showing in testflight and activity tab

Comment: If you are in a hurry, maybe reaching out to Apple directly is the better approach.

Comment: i can wait but they also not reaching out. i want to try all option to get help.

Comment: i am able to solve this by using transporter tool for uploading with new build. but not able to get why xcode directly not happening.